# How does GeometryReader work with Preferences?

Tags: swiftui

Why if I add `.padding(10)` modifier before `.frame(width: width, height: width)` view doesn't show up on the screen? I can't understand this rendering flow.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        TextWithCircle()
    }
}

struct WidthKey: PreferenceKey {
    static let defaultValue: CGFloat? = nil
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat?, nextValue: () -> CGFloat?) {
        value = value ?? nextValue()
    }
}

struct TextWithCircle: View {
    @State private var width: CGFloat? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
            Text("Hello, world")
                .background(
                    GeometryReader { proxy in
                        Color.clear.preference(
                            key: WidthKey.self,
                            value: proxy.size.width
                        )
                    }
                )
                .onPreferenceChange(WidthKey.self) { value in
                    self.width = value
                }
                .padding(10)
                .frame(width: width, height: width)
                .background(Circle().fill(Color.blue))
    }
}
```

If I place `.padding()` modifier right after `Text("Hello, world")` (before first `.background()`) everything is ok. How does it work?

Comment: Think about each modifier being like an envelope. The `padding` can be inside or outside the `background` if it is on the outside the `GeometryReader` doesn't know about it.

Comment: @loremipsum yeah, i know `proxy` will get an actual size of the Text without additional padding in the example above. But i can't understand what's going wrong if i place this `.padding()` before `.frame()`.

Comment: You have obtained the size of the `Text`, then added `.padding()`, then put a `.frame()` over it that tells it it cannot be any bigger than the original `Text`, so it is cutting the `.padding()` back out of the view. A good visual aid for this is to drop .background()` with different colors on everything, and then comment out pieces of code, one at a time. This allows you to visually see what is going on.